# Changing locale in Ubuntu 15.04 VPS is not being saved

Tags: linux, ubuntu, locale

I just bought a VPS and I'm playing it it using SSH.
After a few software packages installations I saw that I had a problem with locales (I need to have `en_US.UTF-8` but I have `Latin1`. I googled it but even after I think I've changed locales then they keep returning to the original ones and I still get problems with software installation.
So, I get:

```
root@myname:~# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pt_PT.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

But before, I have done:

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US:en
export LS_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

So, I can I solve this forever?

PS: I'm doing all this using SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because my `locale` in my local machine is set to Portuguese, which `SSH` forwards to and tries to use on the server, but the server does not have it installed.
I could have stopped forwarding the `locale` environment variable from my local machine to the server. To do that I would have commented the `SendEnv LANG LC_*` line in the local `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file.
Instead I decided to:
1) Generate the `locale` - Generate the English `locale` on the server with `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`
2) Stop accepting `locale` environment variable from my local machine to the server. To do that I commented the `AcceptEnv LANG LC_*` line in the remote `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. Note that for this I had to install the nano package to edit the file (after `sudo apt-get install nano` I just did `nano filename` when I was in the file directory).
3) Set the server `locale` to English - by adding the following lines to my remote `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` files using `nano filename` again (don't forget they are hidden files inside your home directory so they won't appear in a simple `ls` search; you need to use `ls -la` command):

```
export LANGUAGE="en"
export LANG="C"
export LC_MESSAGES="C"
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US:en
export LS_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I also restarted the VM and before that I closed my SSH session and reenter to see if changes were working.